# Encountering: "Error 2000" when trying to jailbreak iOS 5.1.1. What does this mean?

Tags: jailbreak

Using RedSn0w, I tried to jailbreak iOS 5.1.1 on a 3GS and at the first step of "preparing" an error comes at 91% completion saying: "Error 2000". What does this mean and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. turn off your iphone and put it in DFU mode than start redsnow, jailbrake and let it install. it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, how do i put it in DFU mode?

Comment: There's a nice walkthrough here -  http://osxdaily.com/2010/06/24/iphone-dfu-mode-explained-and-how-to-enter-dfu-mode-on-your-iphone/ - you need to hold down certain buttons at different times.

Answer (score 0):

DFU mode is the secret! Try this video out; it helped me a lot:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=fvwp&v=rMujSKuKmnY&NR=1

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info.